# Getting a new chrome extension to work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Trying to get this to work: http://addyosmani.com/blog/autosave-changes-chrome-dev-tools/

I have never worked with node.js nor terminal before and could really use help..THANKS!!!

I followed the steps and I am getting an error through the extension that says URL (file://macintosh%20hd...it gets cut off) doesn't match RegExp /^file:VV(?localhost)?V/ this gets cut off too

This is way out of my league, I really appreciate your help, and I need some pretty detailed steps on what I need to do..THANKS!!!

Comment: How did you get URL that starts with `file://macintosh%20hd`. It supposed to be `file:///` (3 slashes)?
Where did you see "... doesn't match RegExp /^file:VV(?localhost)?V/"?

Comment: Thats what opens up when I preview my local file in browser. That entire message came in the notification drop down in the top right of chrome.

Comment: The problem is somewhere in the path. I see it starts with `file://macintosh%20hd` but I need the whole thing.

Comment: `file://macintosh%20hd/Users/kangaroobin/Local/reubenandhunter/index.html`

Comment: Can you open file:///Users/kangaroobin/Local/reubenandhunter/index.html (without macintosh%20hd) in the browser? Does it work?

Comment: @NVI Thanks!!! That worked perfectly! Wow..so easy! Any idea how to get dreamweaver to show the link that way when previewing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the [chrome-devtools-autosave-server](https://github.com/NV/chrome-devtools-autosave-server). You should install the latest version.